# PCL Point-Cloud-Library cmake install error - OpenMP

Tags: macos, cmake, openmp, osx-mountain-lion, point-cloud-library

this is my first post so please be gentle!

I'm getting what appear to be cmake errors when trying to configure an install of pcl 1.7 in OSX 10.8.5. The error which appears 18 times is:

```
Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
```

and then after the 18 failed searches for OpenMP:

```
Could NOT find OpenMP (missing:  OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS) 
Not found OpenMP
```

I'm also getting a red error (using cmake GUI) stating:

```
CMake Error at cmake/Modules/FindEigen.cmake:25 (file):
  file Internal CMake error when trying to open file:
  /Library/Frameworks/Eigen.framework/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h for
  reading.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:238 (find_package)
```

But then followed in black by:

```
Found Eigen: /Library/Frameworks/Eigen.framework  
Eigen found (include: /Library/Frameworks/Eigen.framework, version: ..)
```

so perhaps this isn't the issue (also there are no references to Eigen in the CMakeError.log.

Any help diagnosing or fixing the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: The C/C++ compiler that comes with recent Xcode versions (Clang) does not support OpenMP.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I'm using default native compilers with XCode as generator. Has anyone else had issues with PCL and Clang and is there a way to remedy this?

Comment: Just compiled PCL 1.6.0 with success despite OpenMC still not being found - must be the Eigen error, any ideas why?

Comment: Maybe this is a problem with your Eigen installation? Did you try reinstalling Eigen? Can you find `Macros.h` in the named location?

Comment: And if you need to use the Omp features you could use GCC...

Answer (score 1):

So it seems the OpenMP errors may be able to be resolved by switching the compiler from Clang to g++, though I haven't done this as I'll be OK without OpenMP. The Eigen error (which was what was halting the build) was fixed by uninstalling then reinstalling MacPorts.

Comment: I'm trying to a CMAKE based project that throws the same OpenMP error. How did you switch from clang to g++ ? I've tried ```cmake -G Xcode -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/llvm-gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/llvm-g++ ..``` and ```cmake -G Xcode -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++ ..``` but no joy